# QT Mingw not able to compile template class

Tags: qt

I am compiling a project using `MSVC2010 compiler` i am compiling it against following library (Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010) In that case compilation is successful with no error.

Now I am trying to compilng a QT app using `minGW` using following library (Qt\4.7.4\mingw).Then i am getting following error.

devicethreadobject.h include following file event.h.
Event.h file contains few template class.

Does MinGW have problem while working with template `?`

Why compilation is successfull with MSVC compiler & fails with MINGW compiler `?`

Event.h file :----

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QEvent>

//String event derived class
template <typename T> class StringEvent : public QEvent
{
   QString m_str;
public:
   explicit StringEvent(const QString val) : QEvent(staticType()), m_str(val)
   {
   }

   void setvalue(QString val)
   {
       m_str = val;
   }

   QString value() const
   {
       return m_str;
   }

   static QEvent::Type staticType()
   {
      static int type = QEvent::registerEventType();
      return static_cast<QEvent::Type>(type);

      /*
        static int type;
      if(type == 0)
      {
          type = QEvent::registerEventType();
      }

         return static_cast<QEvent::Type>(type);*/
   }

   static bool is(const QEvent * ev)
   {
       return ev->type() == staticType();
   }
};

class UpdateEvent : public StringEvent<UpdateEvent>
{
public:
    explicit UpdateEvent(QString val): StringEvent(val)
    {
       //qDebug() << "hello";

    }

};


class ClearEvent  : public StringEvent<ClearEvent>
{
public:
    explicit ClearEvent(QString val): StringEvent(val)
    {

    }
};

#endif // EVENT_H
```

Error :---

```
18:23:08: Running build steps for project CanSewLyzer_vs...
18:23:08: Starting: "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.7.4\mingw\bin\qmake.exe" D:\Stryker\Stryker\Qt\AutoS\CanSewLyzer_err_mingw\CanSewLyzer_vs\CanSewLyzer_vs.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=release"
18:23:09: The process "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.7.4\mingw\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
18:23:09: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `D:/Stryker/Stryker/Qt/AutoS/CanSewLyzer_err_mingw/CanSewLyzer_vs-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Release'
c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/uic.exe ../CanSewLyzer_vs/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'release' -I'.' -I'../CanSewLyzer_vs' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o release/main.o ../CanSewLyzer_vs/main.cpp
In file included from ../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/devicethreadobject.h:8,
                 from ../CanSewLyzer_vs/mainwindow.h:9,
                 from ../CanSewLyzer_vs/main.cpp:2:
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h: In constructor 'UpdateEvent::UpdateEvent(QString)':
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:56: error: class 'UpdateEvent' does not have any field named 'StringEvent'
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:56: error: no matching function for call to 'StringEvent<UpdateEvent>::StringEvent()'
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:18: note: candidates are: StringEvent<T>::StringEvent(QString) [with T = UpdateEvent]
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:15: note:                 StringEvent<UpdateEvent>::StringEvent(const StringEvent<UpdateEvent>&)
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h: In constructor 'ClearEvent::ClearEvent(QString)':
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:68: error: class 'ClearEvent' does not have any field named 'StringEvent'
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:68: error: no matching function for call to 'StringEvent<ClearEvent>::StringEvent()'
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:18: note: candidates are: StringEvent<T>::StringEvent(QString) [with T = ClearEvent]
../CanSewLyzer_vs/../../geny/common/mythread/../event/event.h:15: note:                 StringEvent<ClearEvent>::StringEvent(const StringEvent<ClearEvent>&)
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Stryker/Stryker/Qt/AutoS/CanSewLyzer_err_mingw/CanSewLyzer_vs-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Release'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [release] Error 2
18:23:14: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project CanSewLyzer_vs (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'*
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `MinGW`/`GCC` having issues with templates, it's `MSVC` being permissive about the syntax.

Change

```
explicit UpdateEvent(QString val): StringEvent(val)
...
explicit ClearEvent(QString val): StringEvent(val)
```

With

```
explicit UpdateEvent(QString val): StringEvent<UpdateEvent>(val)
...
explicit ClearEvent(QString val): StringEvent<ClearEvent>(val)
```